# Bind event on element that's not in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds a `<tr>` dynamically, outside it seems that the elements contained in it are not recognized by jQuery because it is not yet loaded into the DOM.

I try to use `.on` function , but it is not working.

Have you an idea ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add_item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nbeTr = $(".tablerow").length;
    if (nbeTr < 10){
      $(".tablerow:last").after("<tr class='filleul'><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><button class='newtr'>X</button></td></tr>");
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".newtr", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Yo");
  });
});
```

Comment: Share your HTML please.

Comment: Fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/z7wk5j1b/

Comment: Based on the fiddle I made ... I guess it doesn't work because you are using the wrong version for Jquery, with v1.6 on the previous fiddle doesn't work but with a higher than 1.7 your code will work https://jsfiddle.net/z7wk5j1b/1/

Comment: Check your consoloe you have this error ? **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function**

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code , Its working.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/525pnx35/1

Comment: @buck Code is woking

Comment: the only thing I would change is giving your dynamically added row a class of `tablerow`

Comment: Hoo yeah, code is working, bad version of jQuery + bad refresh on server ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to register the event listener when creating the button element. Right now you're trying to register click events to undefined elements.

```
// create button
$ele = $("<button class='newtr'>X</button>");
// bind event listener to button
$ele.on("click", function() { alert("hello"); });
// insert $ele into DOM
$target.append($ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Buck your code is working, I think problem is some where else.

See this working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_item").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nbeTr = $(".tablerow").length;
    if (nbeTr < 10) {
      $(".tablerow:last").after("<tr class='tablerow filleul'><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td><button class='newtr'>X</button></td></tr>");
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".newtr", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Yo");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='add_item'>Add item</button>
<table>
  <tr class='tablerow'>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
    <td>c3</td>
    <td>
      <button class='newtr'>X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but this answer doesn't provide any new to the question; doesn't answer at all why this code doesn't work for OP ... You can ask for clarification on the comments as you can see pointing that the actual code works.

Comment: Yes, it's a bad version of jQuery was using and bad refresh (cache maybe ?) It's working now !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was a bad version of jQuery was using.

I just use CDN of last jQuery version and refresh cache and it's working.